# Add Field from Form on createRecord only

Tags: ember.js

I'm looking to override `createRecord` for a model so that I can extract a HTML form value and append it to the JSON body prior to the POST to the REST endpoint.

I'm trying to avoid including the field in the model definition as it is only used once (on create) and never returned from the REST endpoint nor needed when updating a record.

e.g.

```
  {
    "id": "55fd0ff81be9be006737acef",
    "name": "Trujillo",
    "email": "trujillotyson@dentrex.com",
    "createdDate": "2014-05-25T01:59:56 -08:00",
    // Append this to the model JSON
    "stripe_token": "55fd0ff8f342d8ba581a9e06"
  }
```

However, it's not clear as to how to override this—the official docs have [some thin documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_serialize) in the related `serialize` method, but it's not comprehensive.

Where possible I want to lean on the existing method to handle returning the Promise and only append this field.

```
/// app/adapters/some-model.js

export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
    createRecord(store, type, snapshot) {
      var data = this.serialize(snapshot, { includeId: true });
      // How do we achieve this - appending a key with
      // data from the HTML form that `save()` is called from?
      data.set('stripe_token', this.get('stripeToken'));

      // Correct? Still leverage the base method
      // but with our modifed 'data' instead
      return this._super(store, type, data)
    }
});
```

How can I achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right way - to copy and redefine `createRecord` for appropriate adapter. For example for RESTAdapter and ED:2.0.1 [source](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.0.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js)

```
// app/adapters/some-model.js
export default ApplicationAdapter.extend({
  createRecord: function(store, type, snapshot) {
    var data = {};
    var serializer = store.serializerFor(type.modelName);
    var url = this.buildURL(type.modelName, null, snapshot, 'createRecord');

    serializer.serializeIntoHash(data, type, snapshot, { includeId: true });

    // customization
    var stripeToken = //your logic here;
    data['stripe_token'] = stripeToken;
    // customization end

    return this.ajax(url, "POST", { data: data });
  }
});
```

Comment: Great—thanks for clarifying that. Is there a straightforward way to capture the form value so that it's available to createRecord?

Comment: I'd use service. http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/services-and-initializers/services/